# Codeception Acceptance Test Issue with JoomlaBrowser

Tags: development, custom-component, cms-testing

When trying to write a simple Acceptance Test only creating a new Joomla Article Blog Menu Item, I'm doing this:

```
$I->createMenuItem('Blog', 'Articles', 'Category Blog', 'Main Menu');
```

I get this:

```
Step  I create menu item "Blog","Articles","Category Blog","Main Menu"
Fail  CSS or XPath element with link 'Select' was not found.
```

Everything runs as a Github Workflow and all other testing parts are working.

So what fails inside the JoomlaBrowser createMenuItem function is:

```
$this->click(array('link' => "Select"));
```

This is the reduced Report:

[image]

It's default Joomla menu item selection and "createMenuItem" is a default JoomlaBrowser Function. See here:

```
public function createMenuItem($menuTitle, $menuCategory, $menuItem, $menu = 'Main Menu', $language = 'All')
{
    $this->debug("I open the menus page");
    $this->amOnPage('administrator/index.php?option=com_menus&view=menus');
    $this->waitForText('Menus', TIMEOUT, array('css' => 'H1'));
    $this->checkForPhpNoticesOrWarnings();

    $this->debug("I click in the menu: $menu");
    $this->click(array('link' => $menu));
    $this->waitForText('Menus: Items', TIMEOUT, array('css' => 'H1'));
    $this->checkForPhpNoticesOrWarnings();

    $this->debug("I click new");
    $this->click("New");
    $this->waitForText('Menus: New Item', TIMEOUT, array('css' => 'h1'));
    $this->checkForPhpNoticesOrWarnings();
    $this->fillField(array('id' => 'jform_title'), $menuTitle);

    $this->debug("Open the menu types iframe");
    $this->click(array('link' => "Select"));
    $this->waitForElement(array('id' => 'menuTypeModal'), TIMEOUT);
    $this->wait(1);
    $this->switchToIFrame("Menu Item Type");

    $this->debug("Open the menu category: $menuCategory");

    // Open the category
    $this->wait(1);
    $this->waitForElement(array('link' => $menuCategory), TIMEOUT);
    $this->click(array('link' => $menuCategory));

    $this->debug("Choose the menu item type: $menuItem");
    $this->wait(1);
    $this->waitForElement(array('xpath' => "//a[contains(text()[normalize-space()], '$menuItem')]"), TIMEOUT);
    $this->click(array('xpath' => "//div[@id='collapseTypes']//a[contains(text()[normalize-space()], '$menuItem')]"));
    $this->debug('I switch back to the main window');
    $this->switchToIFrame();
    $this->debug('I leave time to the iframe to close');
    $this->wait(2);
    $this->selectOptionInChosen('Language', $language);
    $this->waitForText('Menus: New Item', '30', array('css' => 'h1'));
    $this->debug('I save the menu');
    $this->click("Save");

    $this->waitForText('Menu item saved', TIMEOUT, array('id' => 'system-message-container'));
}
```

Here is the composer packages i'm using:

```
{
    "name": "tests",
    "description": "Tests",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {},
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "^3",
        "joomla-projects/joomla-browser": "~v3",
        "joomla-projects/selenium-server-standalone": "~v3",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.6",
        "behat/gherkin": "^4.4.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a bug and should be reported at https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-browser/issues the "Select" text is part of a span-tag and starts with a white-space, maybe that's the reason codeception can't the link to click.

Comment: OK, i forked and cloned joomlabrowser and changed the `Select` line and when syncin my repos now it works. will try to change it to a more robust xpath selection.

Comment: if you have a better one please submit it to the joomlabrowser repository.

Comment: Colleague of mine wanted to do a pull request but some cs test are failing that have nothing to do with the changed line. Should be no problem to fix.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a bug in the Joomla Browser and has been fixed now.

See https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-browser/pull/216

The current version should be able to create new menuitems.